# Reanimating a creature with X in its cost

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I reanimate an [Apocalypse Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bApocalypse%20Hydra%5d) using [Rise from the Grave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRise%20from%20the%20Grave%5d). How strong is the hydra?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would enter with 0 +1/+1 counters, then get put back into the graveyard for having 0 toughness as a state-based action.

> 107.3f If a card in any zone other than the stack has an {X} in its mana cost, the value of {X} is treated as 0, even if the value of X is defined somewhere within its text.